# Bind repeater via XElement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to bind my repeater via XElement.

In cs file

```
    public void BindList()
    {

        XElement element = LoadXMLElement(GetList()); //Get List is another process its not a problem  I got a list.
        rptrList.DataSource = from x in element.Descendants("List")
                                      select new { Value1 = x.Element("FileName"), Value2 = x.Element("URL"), Value3 = x.Element("Thumb") };
        rptrList.DataBind();

    }
    public  XElement LoadXMLElement(string xmlString)
    {
        XElement element = null;
        try
        {
            element = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to parse string to xmlformat");
        }
        return element;
    }
```

And in ascx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrList" runat="server" 
                    onitemdatabound="rptrTemplateList_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <p>

                                <asp:Label ID="lblTemplateName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FileName") %>'  />

                            </p>
                            <asp:Image ID="imgThubNail" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Thumb") %>' />
                            <br />
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyData" Text="No item To Display" runat="server" Visible="false">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

But in ascx `Eval` is not work.I try `XPath` but no luck.I try to search but nothing find which help me.What is a correct way to bind repeater via `XElement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Eval()` calls are looking for `FileName` and `Thumb`, but the Linq to XML query is returning objects with `Value1`, `Value2`, and `Value3`. Try changing the query...

```
rptrList.DataSource = from x in element.Descendants("List")
                      select new { 
                          FileName = x.Element("FileName"), 
                          URL = x.Element("URL"), 
                          Thumb = x.Element("Thumb") 
                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be preferred to have your query return a list of XElements instead of creating an object.

```
rptrList.DataSource = element.Descendants("List").Elements;
rptrList.DataBind();
```

Once you are sending XElements to the Repeater, your `ItemTemplate` can look like this:

```
<%#CType(Container.DataItem, System.Xml.Linq.XElement).Attribute("FileName").Value%>
```